# How to retrieve asp:CheckBox value from SQL db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table of CheckBoxes that are inserted into a SQL db as 'True' and 'False'. However, I would like to retrieve those values again with a load event, but I'm not able to get them. This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (auditChecklist != null)
    {
        //for loading audit checklist
        getAuditChecklist();
    }

}
```

I tried to retrieve them with the function below, which I thought it might do it:

```
    private void getAuditChecklist()
{

    //int i = 0;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSCV1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string queryString = @"SELECT * FROM AUDIT_CHECKLIST " +
        "WHERE SITE_ID = @SiteID";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
        cmd.Connection = connection;            

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SiteID", //the name of the parameter to map
              System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
              20, //The width of the parameter
              "Site_ID")); //The name of the column source
        //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
        //from the text field
        cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = foo.Site_ID;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {                
            while (reader.Read())
            {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", //the name of the parameter to map
               System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
               20, //The width of the parameter
               "Mount")); //The name of the column source
            //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
            //from the text field
            cmd.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = "True";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", //the name of the parameter to map
               System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
               20, //The width of the parameter
               "Mount")); //The name of the column source
            //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
            //from the text field
            cmd.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = "False";

        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the values and set the controls to the db values or save the control values to the database? The getAuditChecklist method only retrieves the state from the database not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This how I did to read/get checkmark values from the database:

```
    private void getAuditChecklist()
{
SqlCommand cmd = null;
string conn =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string queryString = @"SELECT Mount, Braker, Access, Conn_Net, Log_Book, Pictures, Floor, Cb_Lenght, Channel FROM AUDITOR_CHECKLIST " +
    "WHERE SITE_ID = @SiteID";        

using (SqlConnection connection =
           new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString);
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SiteID", //the name of the parameter to map
          System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, //SqlDbType value
          20, //The width of the parameter
          "SITE_ID")); //The name of the column source
    //Fill the parameter with the value retrieved
    //from the text field
    cmd.Parameters["@SiteID"].Value = foo.Site_ID;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
 {                    
CheckBox1.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Mount")));
CheckBox2.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Braker")));
CheckBox3.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Access")));
CheckBox4.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Conn_Net")));
CheckBox5.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Log_Book")));
CheckBox6.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Pictures")));
CheckBox8.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Floor")));
CheckBox9.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Cb_lenght")));
CheckBox10.Checked = (reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("Channel")));
 } 
reader.Close();
 }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your **Question** properly...The problem is in your **datatypes**.
I think its a bit field.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", SqlDbType.Bit));
sqlCommmand.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, would this method show the checkmark from the db? or in other words, would it retrieve the value and put it in as a checkmark on the checkbox?

Comment: yes you can also do that :
_checkboxName_.checked=dr["Mount"];

Comment: yes you can also do that :
provide true or false to your checkbox...i.e 
`CheckBoxname.checked= true`

select query and then execute it with executereader
`SqlDataReader dr=commandobjectname.ExecuteReader();
While(dr.Read())
{
  _checkboxName_.checked=dr["Mount"];  
}`
Note that Mount is your column name.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your values are *inserted as 'True' and 'False'*, yet you are passing 1 and 0 into an nvarchar field.  Is the database field a nvarchar or a bit?

If it's a bit field, change you parameter to a bit data type:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", SqlDbType.Bit));
sqlCommand.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = 1;
```

If it's an nvarchar field, you should rethink your schema because you should really be using a bit data type.  But, for the sake of the question, you could do that like so:

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mount", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
sqlCommand.Parameters["@Mount"].Value = "True";
```

However, you are adding the `@Mount` parameter, but your `queryString` makes no reference to a `@Mount` parameter.  I'm not sure what your intention is with that, but I imagine that is where your issue lies.

I would recommend you start [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to begin reading data from the database.

Comment: The Database field is a Nvarchar, and I'm trying to retrieve the checkmark from the checkbox, so the user knows what was checked before from their last session. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The equivalent SQL data type for a CheckBox is a `bit` field, so if you want to record the fact that they have a CheckBox marked, you shouldn't be using a `nvarchar` for that in your database.  What if one user's field got unintentionally changed from 'True' to 'Trye'?  Then you lose that piece of data because you can't accurately query it.  A `bit` field removes that possibility.

Comment: I used "True" as a value for that checkbox but for some reason the checkbox is coming up unchecked. It's not displaying the checked value.

Comment: Please see the link I sent you at the end of my answer.  You're not actually retrieving anything from the database because you immediately close your SqlConnection after you ExecuteReader().  That link will tell you how to get the data from the database correctly.

Comment: I used what you suggested, please see above. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you are trying to do.  You are seeing if a checkbox is checked, and then retrieving true/false values from the database.  Do you want to set some other checkboxes to true/false based on those  retrieved values?  Please explain your overall intention in more detail.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I got the solution working. See below for my solution: