# Mark A CheckBox As Checked If SQL Data = 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a column in my sql server database named "option_key", it's a bit column that is either 1 or 0 (one indicates a right answer, 0 indicates wrong). 
I have created a web form that queries the database and returns data into several different TextBoxes and GridViews (it's basically a form that searches an item and returns all pertinent information). I am new to C# and ASP, but I'm basically done.

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to have my CheckBoxes show as checked after the "search" button is clicked and the fields on my form are populated. Essentially, what I need is to have a CheckBox appear as checked if the row in my database = 1, and have the other CheckBoxes not be checked if the row = 0. I am trying to get a checkmark to appear in my CheckBox if the row in my databases column = 1. I have zero code for the checkbox as I am completely lost, but here is some of the code for the form if that helps to clarify at all:

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda3 = new SqlDataAdapter("select(select item_id from item_header ih where related_item_header_id = ih.item_header_id) as [Enemy Item ID], (select item_stem from item_header ih where related_item_header_id = ih.item_header_id) as [Item Stem],[social_order_type] as [Type] FROM[AvokaItemDev].[dbo].[social_order] sc join item_header ih on sc.item_header_id = ih.item_header_id  join social_order_type sct on sc.social_order_type_id = sct.social_order_type_id where item_id ='" + cloneItemID.Text + "'", con);
        DataSet dt3 = new DataSet();
        sda3.Fill(dt3);
        GridView3.DataSource = dt3;
        GridView3.DataBind();


//textbox code
 SqlCommand com12;
        String str12;
        //item_detail code for item status
        str12 = "select m.mcs_desc from mcs_code m left join item_header h on m.mcs_code_id = h.mcs_code_id where h.item_id ='" + cloneItemID.Text + "'";
        com12 = new SqlCommand(str12, con);
        SqlDataReader readerTwelve = com12.ExecuteReader();
        if (readerTwelve.Read())
        {
            txtMCSdesc`enter code here`.Text = readerTwelve["MCS_desc"].ToString();
            readerTwelve.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Where's your code?  There are several ways to do it.  Post what you have so we can give you an answer that matches what you're doing.

Comment: I have zero code related to the checkbox as of now, as I am completely lost. Here is a snippet of my code for a checkbox and gridview though, hopefully that will clarify some:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve asp:CheckBox value from SQL db?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156493/how-to-retrieve-aspcheckbox-value-from-sql-db)

Comment: I don't believe so as that is attempting populate the checkboxes on a load event, however I am attempting to do so on a button click.

Comment: A button click is an event, just like form load.  The principle should be the same, it's just the event that triggers it will be different.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, it looks like I was overthinking this quite a bit.SqlCommand com16;  String str16;  str16 = "select option_key from item_detail d left join item_header h on h.item_header_id = d.item_header_id where d.option_order = 4 and h.item_id = '" + cloneItemID.Text + "'";  com16 = new SqlCommand(str16, con);
SqlDataReader readerSixteen = com16.ExecuteReader();
   while (readerSixteen.Read())
      {
         checkBoxFour.Checked = (readerSixteen.GetBoolean(readerSixteen.GetOrdinal("option_key")));
       }
        readerSixteen.Close(); fixed it for me. thanks a ton guys.

Comment: Don't forget to vote for answers that were useful to your question.

Comment: I do not have the privileges to vote yet, but again, thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

All `CheckBox` controls have a property **IsChecked**.  When you're running your query, you can do something like:

```
bool bChecked = row == 1 ? true : false;
checkbox.IsChecked = bChecked;
```

That, in and of itself, will not work.  It's essentially psuedocode.  But, the moral of the story is to assign the value of the `IsChecked` parameter of the `Checkbox` while you're looking at your database.

Answer (score 0):

I did no understand completely, But if you want manage a check box as a column of your gridview you can put it in a template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" Checked='<%# ((string)Eval("row") == "1") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```